# Displaying and manipulating a tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, coffeescript

I'm building a website where users can store some data in a hierarchical fashion.

Today I have been creating the classes that make up the objects in the tree.

However, I am fairly new to JavaScript/CoffeeScript and client-side scripting and I'm not sure how to design properly.

Take for instance this class that represents a leafnode:

```
class window.LeafNode
  constructor: (@title, @desc, @content) ->

  doesMatch: (query) ->
    (@title.toLowerCase().indexOf query) > -1

  html: ->
    element = document.createElement('li')
    element.innerHTML = @title
    element
```

Here I am giving this class responsibility for several things. One is creating it's own state, which seems reasonable. However, it's also responsible for searching itself and determining a match, so the tree structure is searchable. Finally, it contains an html representation of itself.

While I am uncertain about the searching method, I'm opposed to having html in the model. I don't think it belongs there.

Can you provide some perspective on ways to solve this?

Keep in that the tree should be searchable, serializable and that users should be able to add, delete and move around nodes.

*Note: I have experimented with AngularJS, but decided against it, because it contains a whole slew of abstractions that are quite overwhelming for someone new to JavaScript like me. Therefore, I would like advice that doesn't require the use of frameworks or third party libraries.*

Comment: `doesMatch` seems fair enough for simple cases, moving your `html` method to a separate `LeafNodeView` class might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking something similar. But what if I want multiple views? For instance a mobile friendly version.

I imagine some sort of seperation where the model somehow *emits* a change and then something else is responsible for handling that change and updating the DOM. I would like the model to be independent of the view.

Comment: If you want multiple views then make multiple views, that name was just illustrative; there are all kinds of ways to manage different views for different environments and the techniques aren't really specific to JavaScript. Sounds like you're about to recreate a framework such as [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org).

Comment: I have looked a bit at Backbone JS, which could certainly be interesting in the future, but for now I'd like to implement the solutions myself to become familiar with JS and keep things lightweight.

Comment: The Backbone source is fairly simple and readable so you could study it to see how they do things.